# Rails initializer - what is wrong

Tags: ruby-on-rails, initializer

This is my first initializer and I do not understand what is wrong.

`config\initializers\other_server.rb`:

```
OtherServer.setup do |config|
  config.first_server_login = 'qwertyuiop'
  config.first_server_password = '12345'
end
```

`lib\other_server_base.rb`:

```
module OtherServer
  mattr_accessor :first_server_login
  @@first_server_login = nil

  mattr_accessor :first_server_password
  @@first_server_password = nil

  def self.setup
    yield self
  end

  class Base
    def self.session_id
      # ................
      # How to access first_server_login and first_server_password here?
      res = authenticate({
          login: first_server_login,
          pass: first_server_password })
      # ................
    end
  end
end
```

`lib\other_server.rb`:

```
module OtherServer
  class OtherServer < Base
    # ................
  end
end
```

How to access `first_server_login` and `first_server_password` in `OtherServer::Base` class?

If I call `OtherServer.first_server_login` it complains about absence of `OtherServer::OtherServer.first_server_login` member.

Comment: Files from lib are loaded before your initializers. I think its better to store credentials like that in .yml file. Give a chance config/secrets.yml. You will be able to load login and password exactly from .yml with YAML.load_file('path to file') command. Look for more: http://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/4_1_release_notes.html

Comment: You shouldn't store credentials in yml but in env variables.

Comment: @methyl: that's not the point. Of course I will load them from environment variables... later, but do you know something about the question's subject?

Comment: @zachar: Ruby is an interpreted language what means that yes, class definitions from `lib` could be loaded earlier than initializers, but their usage happens later, and methods' accessibility is evaluated at usage time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've found the right answer:

A module and a class inside of it CAN have same names. In my case the module members should be referenced as:

```
::OtherServer.first_server_login
```

That's all.

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, you can not use the same identifier for both a module and a class.

```
module Test;end # => nil
class Test;end  # => TypeError: Test is not a class
```

Beyond that, regarding your first snippet, the variable would not be able to be resolved as it would try to resolve it within the `Base` class which doesn't extend `OtherServer` (is just defined within its namespace). You could still access it like that:

```
class Base
  def self.session_id      
    OtherServer.first_server_login # this works
  end
end
```